# How to create user specific MongoDB collections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I guess this is more of a procedural question than a specific coding question, but I have a node application and am using the DHTMLX calendar working on it. I want each user to have an individual collection of events for their specific calendar.

Right now the way I've implemented it, everyone sees the same calendar and can edit it. I want it so each user has their own editable calendar.  How can I do this? I tried using req.user but the app crashes saying req is not defined. I am very new to javascript so I am probably doing this completely wrong.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

here is the portion of my app.js where I've implemented the calendar:

```
    var db = require('mongoskin').db("myAtlasClusterLink", { w: 0});
    db.bind('event');


    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.get('/init', function(req, res){
        db.event.insert({ 
            text:"My test event A", 
            start_date: new Date(2018,8,1),
            end_date:   new Date(2018,8,5)
        });
        db.event.insert({ 
            text:"My test event B", 
            start_date: new Date(2018,8,19),
            end_date:   new Date(2018,8,24)
        });
        db.event.insert({ 
            text:"Morning event", 
            start_date: new Date(2018,8,4,4,0),
            end_date:   new Date(2018,8,4,14,0)
        });
        db.event.insert({ 
            text:"One more test event", 
            start_date: new Date(2018,8,3),
            end_date:   new Date(2018,8,8),
            color: "#DD8616"
        });

        res.send("Test events were added to the database")
    });


    app.get('/data', function(req, res){
        db.event.find().toArray(function(err, data){
            //set id property for all records
            console.log(err);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                data[i].id = data[i]._id;

            //output response
            res.send(data);
        });
    });


    app.post('/data', function(req, res){
        var data = req.body;
        var mode = data["!nativeeditor_status"];
        var sid = data.id;
        var tid = sid;

        delete data.id;
        delete data.gr_id;
        delete data["!nativeeditor_status"];


        function update_response(err, result){
            if (err)
                mode = "error";
            else if (mode == "inserted")
                tid = data._id;

            res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            res.send({action: mode, sid: sid, tid: tid});
        }

        if (mode == "updated")
            db.event.updateById( sid, data, update_response);
        else if (mode == "inserted")
            db.event.insert(data, update_response);
        else if (mode == "deleted")
            db.event.removeById( sid, update_response);
        else
            res.send("Not supported operation");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code about the current user here.. You'll need the server to differentiate a user from another (like what [this package](https://github.com/expressjs/session) provides, for instance), and a set of routes, UI and client-side storage for the users to log in/out and send requests with their current session's identifier. But this is a whole different subject.

Then you can either:

- store all events in the same collection and add a field telling who owns which event
- derive a collection name from the user's unique data (some ID) for each calendar

From here I'd store everything in the same collection because it's the same "kind" of data, and it will be easier to augment the system when/if you want to share events between users.

Comment: I am using express-session and called it like this in my app.js:  `app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);`

Comment: Oh then you [see](https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsession) why `req.user` isn't defined! ;)

Comment: I'm sorry but like I said I'm extremely new to all of this. Why is req.user not defined? And how can I derive a collection name from their unique data? That sounds like what I was trying to do.

Comment: Question is: why would `req.user` be defined, actually? `express-session`'s documentation says it gives session information (i.e. user information) in `req.session`, not in `req.user`. About user's data: seems like you just create a (temporary, naturally temporary) session, but there is no matching a (persisted, really persisted) user. You probably need credentials (like username/password) to match a _real_ user so that you can bind a user to a session. But like I said, it's a whole different subject. Look for [tutorials or examples](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=node+express+session+example).

Comment: thank you for pointing me to some good examples, I will look into this more!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should think of a way to distinguish current user from others. There are a few ways to do that:

- using just a field in request body, containing username or similar data, and then respond with the user data.
- using passport.js for user creation and authentication ([Easy Node Authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local)), then use user sessions to know who is sending the request. Based on that you can respond with appropriate data.

either way you need a better database schema to do this. I'd recommend using a separate collection for users, and another one for calendar data. Then reference calendar data in user schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/MyDatabase');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      username: String,
      calendars: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
          ref: 'Calendar'
      },
    });

const CalendarSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      // calendar data here
    });
const UserDetails = mongoose.model('User', userSchema );
```

just make sure when you are creating a calendar, add it to the corresponding user calendars array:

```
Calendar.create(newCalendarDataObj, function(error, createdCalendar){

    User.findOne({username: usernameGotFromBody}, function(error, foundUser){

        foundUser.calendars.push(createdCalendar);
        foundUser.save();        
    }
});
```